# Wordpress: Posting a page does not display in my site

Tags: wordpress

I created a new page for my wordpress site. Then I published it
and waited and waited and waited.

In another browser I can see the URL of the page at https://craftsmanshipforsoftware.wordpress.com/linux-sockets-which-process-is-listening-to-a-port/?preview_id=188&preview_nonce=cc825aeff3&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true
but the Recent Posts does not have this page. I am using as few plugins as possible - just the default.

The main page at https://craftsmanshipforsoftware.com/ likewise does not display this new page.

In the dashboard under Posts, this new post does not appear.

I have waited over an hour to see this post appear.

I should be able to simply Publish a new post and have it appear on
my site within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see another post show up under "Recent Posts" you need to create a blog post, not a page. Pages are different than posts and will not show up in your recent posts.

Add this content by clicking `Add` next to blog posts from the wordpress.com dashboard. You will not have to wait after you have published it for it to show up.

Comment: Thank you. I was adding a page instead of a post. Very confusing names indeed! I deleted the page and created a post and this worked. I wasted a few hours dorking around with this "problem".